# unable to locate VCProject (Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll) in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, visual-studio-addins

Not getting VC Project in VS 2017.

I am using VS 2017 to migrate one of the plugins already working in 2010.
But on the build environment  i am not able to Create VCProject

```
Projects projs = appDTE.Solution.Projects;
foreach(Project proj in projs)
{
    VCProject vcProj = proj as VCProject;
    IVCCollection oConfig = vcProj.Configurations as IVCCollection;
   // Do some stuff
}
```

The Dll required is not available in the installation.
Where can i find the Dll. Do i need to install any additional packages ?
or there is any workaround for the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your VS2017 support VC++ project development. You need to install VC++ components through Visual Studio installer and choose the C++ related workloads as below screenshot shows.

[image]

In my VS2017, the Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll exist in installation path\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VC\Project and installation path\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies.